# Repeating animation in jQuery

Tags: jquery, loops

Looking for a better solution to animate days from 1 to 9. Here is the code.

```
    var div = $("<p id='dd1'>Day 1</p>");
    $('#dd1').transition({
        scale: 2.2
    });
    $("#day").empty().append(div);
    for (var i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
        $('#dd' + i).transition({
            scale: 1.1,
            x: 180
        }, 4000, function () {
            var div = $("<p id='dd'" + (i + 1) + ">Day " + (i + 1) + "</p>");
            $("#day").empty().append(div);
        });
        setTimeout(function () {
            // blah blah
        }, 1000);
    }
```

Comment: I'm assuming this doesn't work...at all? Correct?

Comment: Are you using [this plugin](http://ricostacruz.com/jquery.transit/)?

Comment: Yes, it just shows Day 1 and then Day 11, because of the for loop, I need to pause the for loop somehow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way-

You have issues in

- Concatenation of id i.e  `"<p id='dd'" + (i + 1) + ">Day "` you are closing the quotes after dd which should be in the beginning of next string.
- The transition is async, you need to invoke the next transition on the complete callback of the first one. Your for loop runs completely before your second transition happens so the `i` has value of 11 and thats what you are seeing.

JS:

```
var div = $("<p id='dd1'>Day 1</p>"), i=1;
$('#dd1').transition({
    scale: 2.2
});
$("#day").empty().append(div);

function transit(){ //wrap it in function
    $('#dd' + i).transition({ 
        scale: 1.1,
        x: 180
    }, 4000, function () {
        var div = $("<p id='dd" + (i + 1) + "'>Day " + (i + 1) + "</p>");
        $("#day").empty().append(div);
        if(i <= 10){ //once complete check if you want to animate more if so call that again
            setTimeout(function(){
                transit(i++);
            },0);

        }
    });
}
transit(); //invoke to startup.
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/25MhE/)**